# How to get data from Push Notification in WatchOs and handle push notifications action button click event

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

(1) I want to get Data from Push Notification and assign to UIButton and UILabel in Static Notification Interface

(2) How to handle Push Notification action button click event

How to get data from this method `- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletion:(void(^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType interface)) completionHandler`

Below methods are deprecated Please do not use this method for solutions

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** When `Push Notification` is delivered to the device, iOS itself handles the display of data in notification's default interface.

In case you want to change to change the notification's interface, use **Notifications Content Extension**.

**2.** When the `Push Notification` is delivered to the device, we get the callback in `UIApplicationDelegate’s` method -- `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` method.

The `payload` of `push notification` is received in the `userInfo` dictionary of this method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    print("Push Notification Payload:\n\(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

[Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ios-10-notifications-inshorts-all-in-one-ad727e03983a) you can find the detailed discussion on handling `Push Notifications`.

Comment: {
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "Test message123",
            "title": "Optional123 title"
        },
        "category": "myCategory",
        "thread-id":"5280"
    },
    
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
        {
            "title": "FB",
            "identifier": "firstButtonAction"
        }
    ],
    
    
    "Amount": "USD 20",
    "At": "Mc Donalds",
    "When": "Today",
}

Comment: I want to get "Amount" and "At" and "When"

Value

Comment: Friend I am talking about Watchkit Push Notifications

Comment: I am not talking about Notification Service extension
I am talking about WatchKit Push Notification

Answer (score -1):

I think this one help you , i am writing on  Local Notifications

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Toget the Permissions
        self.initNotificationSetUpCheck()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func LocalNotificationClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        //Notifdication Conntent Body
        let localNotification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        localNotification.title = "Rize"
        localNotification.subtitle = "Ios Developers"
        localNotification.body = "Welcome"

        //Notification Triggring
        let notificationTriger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats:false)
        // Notification Request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Notification1", content: localNotification, trigger: notificationTriger)
        //Ad Notification Request
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    }

    func initNotificationSetUpCheck(){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert], completionHandler:{(success,error) in
            if success {
               print("Permission Granted!")
            }else{
              print("There was a problem!")
            }
        })

    }

}

extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    //for displaying notification when app is in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //If you don't want to show notification when app is open, do something here else and make a return here.
        //Even you you don't implement this delegate method, you will not see the notification on the specified controller. So, you have to implement this delegate and make sure the below line execute. i.e. completionHandler.

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }


    // For handling tap and user actions
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case "Notification1":
            print("Action First Tapped")
        case "action2":
            print("Action Second Tapped")
        default:
            break
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not talking about Notification Service extension
I am talking about WatchKit Push Notification

Comment: @AnkurPatel Have you found solution for this?